# Java threading correct way of implementation

Tags: java

The main point of this project is to add a timestamp to the database each second.

***What i need.***

**1.** BackgroundTask for adding generated timestamp to db.

**2.** BackgroundTask for adding data to `Buffer` while server connection is offline.

**3.** Add the data that was saved to the buffer inside the db, while saving new `timestamps` while the app is working

**I have compleated the 1st and 2nd part but having trouble figuring out the 3rd part.**

I have 2 thread classes and both implement `Runnable`.

When server status is positive, `Thread` **A** adds data to database.

When server status is negative `Thread` **B** creates a `Buffer` and stores the data there.

Now I need `Thread` **C** , that tries to connect to the server every 5 seconds and when it establishes the connection `Thread` **B** should somehow implement the data to database(in `FIFO` order) .

I'm having trouble figuring out what to do with the threads and the correct way of implementing further functionality, could someone give me a navigation of how I should implement the following functionality?

Comment: Few problems here:
1. You present a solution without presenting the problem you are trying to solve. Just by looking at your solution it seems that you chose a bad solution.
2. Your question is vague. It is unclear what is the actual problem that you encounter in the implementation.

Comment: If you have a database that could be up and down every five seconds, I think you're going to need some journaling.  How does thread B ever know if the data it just attempted to write got through correctly or not?

Comment: @selalerer i've updated the question, maybe it will be of help.

Answer (score 2):

How about using BlockingQueue and specifically LinkedBlockingQueue(FIFO)?

Thread A will keep adding the data in queue no matter the connection is available or not and thread B will try to read and commit to DB so in case of no data in queue Thread B will block and wait for data .

Note : Go for unbounded Blocking queue if you want to ensure no tasks are rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it using two threads, thread **A** would write to a `LinkedList` every second, and that's all thread **A** would be concerned about; and thread **B** to continuously read from the head (`LinkedList.remove()`) and attempt to upload it to the database, this way if it fails you can retry indefinitely until it succeeds and then continue reading the head of the LinkedList.

However, you would have to keep thread safety in mind. That being said, I think you should be fine if you just set thread **B** to run half a second behind thread **A** since thread **B** would never get ahead of thread **A**, even if every single upload to the database is successful.

Comment: i love the idea, i will try it out :)